# Store image annotations in database without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to store the annotations generated on the image in the database. I have used [Annotorious API](https://annotorious.github.io/index.html) for generating the annotation. The API says that:

> Some versions of Annotorious conflict with jQuery. When using Annotorious and jQuery on the same page, you should put jQuery into no-conflict mode, and either assign a new variable name to jQuery's $ alias or, alternatively, wrap your jQuery code into a function where you can use the $ alias in the local scope,

like so:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
    $('div').hide();
});
```

**myAnnotations.php:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict();
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="annotorious.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-dark/annotorious-dark.css" />

<script>
anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated', function(annotation) {
        var anno_text = annotation.text;
        var anno_x =annotation.shapes[0].geometry.x;
        var anno_y = annotation.shapes[0].geometry.y;
        var anno_width = annotation.shapes[0].geometry.width;
        var anno_height= annotation.shapes[0].geometry.height;

        jQuery.post("insert-note.php",
            {anno_text:anno_text,anno_x:anno_x,anno_y:anno_y,anno_width:anno_width,anno_height:anno_height}
            );
    });
</script>
```

**insert-data.php:**

```
<?php
$anno_text = $_POST['anno_text'];
$anno_x = $_POST['anno_x'];
$anno_y = $_POST['anno_y'];
$anno_width = $_POST['anno_width'];
$anno_height = $_POST['anno_height'];
$sql = "insert into `notes`(`note`,`annox`,`annoy`,`anno_width`,`anno_height`) VALUES ('$anno_text','$anno_x','$anno_y','$anno_width','anno_height')";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysqli_errno($dbcon));
?>
```

This is neither storing the values in the database nor showing any php or mysql error.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Please do some debugging. Check the network tab in your browsers dev tools to see if it actually makes a request, what the request contains and what the actual response is. Check what the `$_POST`-array contains. Do some console.log() and check if your code even enters the `onAnnotationCreated`-callback. You could also add a success and error callback handler to your `jQuery.post()`-request. Btw, have you even checked your console for errors? Check these things and edit your question to include the results.

Comment: Is that your complete `insert-data..php`-file? Is it a copy/paste or is this `$_POSt['anno_width'];` (should be `$_POST`) only a typo here on SO or is it in the real code as well?

Comment: The programs executes the **onAnnotationCreated** block. I check it using the console.log and there is no javascript/jQuery or php error. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Ok. Now you should keep debugging it with the rest of my suggestions. We have no idea what happens, which is why it's super important that you do extensive debugging and _edit your question_ to include all the results.

Comment: I did not make the database connection, that's why it was not working. Thank You @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**insert-data.php:**

```
$anno_x = (double) $_POST['anno_x'];
$anno_y = (double) $_POST['anno_y'];
$anno_width = (double) $_POST['anno_width'];
$anno_height = (double) $_POST['anno_height'];
```

It worked.